# Replace words in array with words from dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a JSON output from a public API that returns codes instead of strings. I am able to put the strings that I need into an array, getting:

```
OutNames = ["f1", "c2", "b3"]
```

based on a PDF, I want to translate the codes into words, so that I can generate a list to display from it.

```
dictionary : any =  {"f1": "Baseball", "b3" : "Soccer" ,"c2": "Football"}
```

I try the following, but always get an error.

```
this.OutNames = this.OutNames

      .map(function(each_element){
        each_element.replace(/[a-z]/gi, k => dictionary[k])});
```

Desired result:

```
Array = ["Baseball", "Football", "Soccer"]
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. You just need to return the dictionary lookups from `map()`. No need to call `replace()`. `map()` will return a new array — you can overwrite the old value if you want, but here I just assigned to a different variable to make it clearer.

```js
OutNames = ["f1", "c2", "b3"]

dictionary = {
  "f1": "Baseball",
  "b3": "Soccer",
  "c2": "Football"
}
let replaced = OutNames.map(el => dictionary[el])
console.log(replaced)
```